# добавление класса через js

Tags: javascript, opencart

Стоит опенкарт и у меня есть меню статичное, но к ним надо было добавить класс active чтобы когда были активны был другой цвет блока

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var url=document.location.href;
      $.each($("div.left-menu .list-group-item.leftje"),function(){
        if(this.href==url){
          $(this).addClass('active');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Но у меня есть одна проблема, главная страница ссылкой site.ru если нажать на главная то превращается site.ru/index.php?route=common/home, то тогда соответственно нету этого класса, а так же хочу сделать чтобы актив на одном блоке всегда был включен если ссылка начинается с http://tonymoly.cosmos-team.ru/index.php?route=product/ дальше любой другой текст
Возможно ли сделать такое?

UPD
Ссылки такого вида

```
<a class="list-group-item leftje" href="http://site.ru">Магазин</a>
<a class="list-group-item leftje" href="http://site.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=6">Доставка</a>
<a class="list-group-item leftje" href="http://site.ru/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=7">Оплата</a>
<a class="list-group-item leftje" href="http://site.ru/index.php?route=information/contact">Контакты</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сравнивайте `pathname`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var pathname=document.location.pathname;
    $.each($("div.left-menu .list-group-item.leftje"),function(){
      if(this.pathname==pathname){
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Сделал так, но тогда все кроме главной стали активными, ихние пути добавил к вопросу

Comment: Если у Вас вся навигация происходит по GET параметрам, то сделйте так:
```jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var search=window.location.search;
    $.each($("div.left-menu .list-group-item.leftje"),function(){
      if(this.search==search){
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
 });```